# Text box by default shouldnt scroll to the end

Tags: vba, excel, textbox

My text box in VBA, by default scrolls to the bottom. I dont want this. I want the scroll bar to remain at the top when the userform displays.

Solution?

Answer (score 4):

In the UserForm's `Initialize` event, set the starting point of the cursor to TextBox's start using `.SelStart`

For example.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim sSample As String
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 10
        sSample = sSample & "Blah Blah" & i & vbNewLine
    Next i

    TextBox1.Text = sSample

    '~~> Set to starting point
    TextBox1.SelStart = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: This works, but once you click on the textbox it automatically scrolls to the bottom.

Comment: No it doesn't for me.

Comment: @vardhanamdaga: I just thought of something. Is the text one continuous line? are are you using `vbNewLine` as a new line separator?

Comment: Yes using vbNewLine as a separator. Is that why it goes down?

Comment: No. It shouldn't go down and I am unable to reproduce it. Which excel version are you using? Also may I see your excel file?

Comment: Unofortunately, I cant share the files online. I,m writing from my office and all sharing methods are blocked. My gmail id is vardhanam.daga@gmail.com. Send me a msg and I will forward you the file.

Answer (score 1):

In the UserForm's Initialize event, you can use textbox1.curline=0

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

```
TextBox1.SetFocus ' to make next line work, first we must set focus on Textbox
TextBox1.CurLine = 0
```

End Sub